# Check for token validity periodically Angular

Tags: angular, authentication, session

I have an angular application with a HTTP interceptor which sends a JWT token as the bearer on all requests. In the case of the backed returns 401 (i.e. token is expired) the Angular application "logs out" and clears the token and user from local storage.

What I do not like in this setup is that the token has a limited validity, but if I leave the browser and come back, or if the token times out, the menus are still shown.

I am having some issues deciding on the best approach.

One idea I had was to implement a timer upon login

```
let tokenvalidity = this.token.get('exp') - timeNow;

function checkToken() {
   //check token valid
   if(token.get('exp')> timeNow){
     //delete localstorage, logout
     localstorage.delete('token');
     this.user = null;
   }
}

setTimeout(checkToken, 1000);
```

However, this does not handle the situation where the browser/tab has been closed. I am considering something running on a shorter timer, as well as on focus of the tab, to check validity, and either prompting for extension (if remaining time is < 1 min) or clearing the session and logging out instead. I am just fuzzy on the best practices for angular.

... and the second question: Where do I put the code (in the navbar or the authentication service?)